# Exclude files from search in VSCode's extension

Tags: vscode-extensions

My VSCode extension creates a database of symbols and stores it along the project. I'd like to automatically exclude this file from search results (it would be even better to exclude it from file explorer).

Is there a way how can I modify "search.exclude" from my extension or can I set such a setting in my extension's package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API for you to *contribute* to `search.exclude` and/or `files.exclude` settings, so you are out of luck on this.

On the other hand, you can make your extension to update the User Settings using `workspace.getConfiguration("section").update("section")` API. With that, `search.exclude` and/or `files.exclude` settings could de updated to respect the symbols you want to be ignored.

But, I would suggest you to warn the users about this process, asking for their approval, before effectively updating the setting. Personally, I don't do this, and prefer that extensions that don't do this as well, but I understand sometimes this is necessary/inevitable.

Hope this helps